# Linux Mint: "Move to monitor 2": but I don't have a second monitor. How do I fix this?

Tags: linux-mint, monitors

I have a fresh install (about a week old) of Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca (love the name!), Cinnamon edition on my laptop.

If I right click on a tab, I get the option "Move to monitor 2".  The problem is that I don't have a monitor 2.  Here's a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of "Move to monitor 2"]

Also oddly, if I take a screenshot, it shows two screens (one I'm unable to access).  See below:

[image: A full screenshot]

> **Q**: How do I fix this?  I only want one monitor (the laptop monitor).

There doesn't seem to be anything relevant in System Settings.  I'm a new user (after switching from Ubuntu), so I might be missing something obvious.

I'm not sure if this is any use, but the contents of `/home/becky/.xsession-errors` is [here](http://pastebin.com/nZJvsVqP) and the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is [here](http://pastebin.com/4VArbmiz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a partial answer to my own question.  I opened up Display (which is not in System Settings?):

[image: Display from menu]

After which, I disabled the second (phantom) monitor:

[image: Disabling the second monitor]

This isn't ideal; since I've still got a second monitor detected, but it should prevent me losing windows to the phantom monitor.